# php code, is it slow or wrong?

Tags: php, zend-studio

"multiple annotations found at this line"

i have been using aptana and other IDE before, but never gave me this error, but yesterday i installed zend studio and it was giving following error in all my code where i have assigned and also check if condition at same time.

```
code:
line 16: if ($message_array = @unserialize($e->getMessage()))
line 17:    $message = $message_array;
```

on all if condition, where i assigned the value to a variable and also check if the variable is true/false, it gives me error "multiple annotations found at this line"

Comment: Suppressing error with @ is always bad!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, that syntax is typically flagged by most decent IDEs as "Accidental Assignment" (since it's not obvious if you meant `=` or `==`).  Most will allow you to wrap it in a `()` to silence the error (since then it's apparent you want the result rather than a test):

```
if (($message_array = @unserialize($e->getMessage()))) {
}
```

Also, for readability and maintainability, I would suggest a few things there.

First, use braces.  Since it's only a special case that lets you not use them, I personally think it's better form to always use them so that it's clear what was meant.

Second, do all asignment outside of the `if` clause.  It makes it more explicit and easier to tell at a quick glance what you meant.  Plus it looks less cluttered.

```
$message_array = @unserialize($e->getMessage());
if ($message_array) {
    ...
}
```

Third, I would suggest avoiding the `@` operator.  To me it's a sign of code-rot.  While I know it's easy to use and easier than properly handling the error, I think it's just a short-cut that will make life harder for you.  You can avoid it in a few ways.  First, you can check the string before you pass it to `unserialize`.  Make sure it's non-empty, a string, etc.  Secondly, you can install an [`error handler`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to throw exceptions on PHP errors (what I do).  That way, you just wrap the `unserialize` call in a `try {} catch(){}` block.  It's nicer since you actually can inspect the error rather than just trusting that the thrown error is what you think it is...

Answer (score 3):

That is not an actual error. Instead the IDE has found more than one error, warnings or hints at the same code line.

You can look at the Problems tab to see the actual errors and warnings.

Comment: there isnt an error on the page, but i was asking as programming wise, is it not recommended to do that way?